# Javascript remotefunction won't work when at the bottom of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, pageload

I have remote function that NOT honor and stop working when I move jQuery scripts at the bottom of page (for page faster load). how can I fix it? thank You in advance.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<?php echo $ajax->remoteFunction(array('url' => array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'go', $user_obj['User']['id']), 'update' => 'engagePost')); ?>
</script>

<div id="engagePost"></div>
```

Comment: You can use jquery's `ready` method for that. https://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 2):

The browser reads the page from the top to the bottom. In your case the function you want to call is written at the top of the page and as you don't wrap it into some `onload` or `document.ready` event it gets executed immediatly.
But the required JQuery scripts are not loaded until the browser has written the corrosponding script tags.

```html
<script>
  remoteFunction()
</script>
<div>
  <!--Page Content-->
</div>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
```

Is causing the problem, insert the JQuery scripts before the function call

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
  remoteFunction()
</script>
<div>
  <!--Page Content-->
</div>
```

And for the best practice to make sure JQuery is loaded you can add the

```
$(document).ready(function () { //call function here })
```

event into your html.